# Can I submit another update if my binary is already approved

Tags: appstore-approval

Currently I have a new binary that has just been approved - (developer release)

And the team decided to make some UI changes.

Now, if we were to submit the updated binary.

If the update were to get rejected, is it possible for us to still release the binary that was previously approved (developer release)?

Basically, we are time constrained to release the product in 3 days, and we want to understand if squeezing in a update makes sense. Ideally, if possible, we don't want the customer to see the binary that is just approved but the new one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Apple Customer Support, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TylerH Well i believe this is a question many developer will face. And Apple Customer Support does not deal with developers. And Apple Developer Forum is a joke compare to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the update were to get rejected, is it possible for us to still
>   release the binary that was previously approved (developer release)?

Yes it is, since it has passed Apple approval according to [Apple Review Guidelines.](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) and the new version will not have replaced your already approved app.

I recommend requesting an [Expedite Request](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#after-you-submit).

Note that, if this were the case, anyone submitting an update would, in case of rejection, have their apps taken down.

Comment: Are you saying app only risks a take down if app is rejected in expedite request? Otherwise it is fine? in that i could release the approved app.

Comment: No the expedite request is just a more urgent request. Nothing else changes.

Comment: So in what scenario does my app risks a take down?

Comment: Only pending updates risk rejection but already approved apps are safe unless other violations or variations to Apple Terms and conditions occur.

Comment: So, in order to submit a new version (v2) for review while i have got a pending developer release (v1). I had to cancel my current pending release (v1). If that new version (v2) doesn't go through for any reason. I still need to put my old version (v1) up for review? Its just that the previous approved version(v1) will be very quick to pass review.?

Comment: If v1 did't pass review you have to start over and it will not be quick...